# Ubuntu/Mint (trusty) : Wifi keeps shutting down

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, wifi, networkmanager

I Run Mint on my desktop and I'm facing a very annoying problem : wifi keeps shutting down after a few minutes or a few hours and it never comes back automatically.

To restore network, I have to manually run :

`sudo service network-manager restart`

I have several other devices connected and no problem with them.

My network controller :

```
lspci | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Linux :

```
uname -a
Linux nunux 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Log :

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog

<incoming wifi permanent shutdown, starting from these lines>

Jan 17 14:27:25 nunux wpa_supplicant[976]: message repeated 5 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux wpa_supplicant[976]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc reason=4 locally_generated=1
Jan 17 14:27:31 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: message repeated 5 times: [ <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted]
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <warn> Connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux kernel: [702301.796637] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux kernel: [702301.802743] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux kernel: [702301.802745] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux kernel: [702301.802747] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux kernel: [702301.802749] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux kernel: [702301.802750] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux kernel: [702301.802751] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux kernel: [702301.802752] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux wpa_supplicant[976]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Jan 17 14:27:50 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 17 14:27:52 nunux wpa_supplicant[976]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc (SSID='freebox_cyrille' freq=2462 MHz)
Jan 17 14:27:52 nunux kernel: [702303.549641] wlan0: authenticate with 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc
Jan 17 14:27:52 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 17 14:27:52 nunux kernel: [702303.564745] wlan0: send auth to 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc (try 1/3)
Jan 17 14:27:52 nunux kernel: [702303.690627] wlan0: send auth to 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc (try 2/3)
Jan 17 14:27:52 nunux kernel: [702303.773740] wlan0: send auth to 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc (try 3/3)
Jan 17 14:27:52 nunux kernel: [702303.892245] wlan0: authentication with 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc timed out
Jan 17 14:27:52 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): roamed from BSSID 16:AE:67:0D:AA:DC (freebox_cyrille) to (none) ((none))
Jan 17 14:27:52 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jan 17 14:27:53 nunux wpa_supplicant[976]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Jan 17 14:27:53 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 17 14:27:54 nunux wpa_supplicant[976]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc (SSID='freebox_cyrille' freq=2462 MHz)
Jan 17 14:27:54 nunux kernel: [702306.080545] wlan0: authenticate with 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc
Jan 17 14:27:54 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 17 14:27:54 nunux kernel: [702306.095800] wlan0: direct probe to 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc (try 1/3)
Jan 17 14:27:55 nunux kernel: [702306.299217] wlan0: direct probe to 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc (try 2/3)
Jan 17 14:27:55 nunux kernel: [702306.503176] wlan0: direct probe to 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc (try 3/3)
Jan 17 14:27:55 nunux kernel: [702306.707096] wlan0: authentication with 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc timed out
Jan 17 14:27:55 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jan 17 14:27:56 nunux wpa_supplicant[976]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Jan 17 14:27:56 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 17 14:27:58 nunux wpa_supplicant[976]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc (SSID='freebox_cyrille' freq=2462 MHz)
Jan 17 14:27:58 nunux kernel: [702309.395341] wlan0: authenticate with 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc
Jan 17 14:27:58 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 17 14:27:58 nunux kernel: [702309.410560] wlan0: direct probe to 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc (try 1/3)
Jan 17 14:27:58 nunux kernel: [702309.614027] wlan0: direct probe to 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc (try 2/3)
Jan 17 14:27:58 nunux kernel: [702309.817970] wlan0: direct probe to 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc (try 3/3)
Jan 17 14:27:58 nunux kernel: [702310.021894] wlan0: authentication with 16:ae:67:0d:aa:dc timed out
Jan 17 14:27:58 nunux wpa_supplicant[976]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="freebox_cyrille" auth_failures=1 duration=10
Jan 17 14:27:58 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jan 17 14:28:03 nunux wpa_supplicant[976]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Jan 17 14:28:03 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <warn> (wlan0): link timed out.
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: activated -> failed (reason 'SSID not found') [100 120 53]
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'Auto freebox_cyrille'
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux dbus[586]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux dbus[586]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 28011
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux avahi-daemon[694]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::eade:27ff:fe08:a434 on wlan0.
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux avahi-daemon[694]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::eade:27ff:fe08:a434.
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux avahi-daemon[694]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux kernel: [702317.110822] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux avahi-daemon[694]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.11 on wlan0.
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux avahi-daemon[694]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.11.
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux avahi-daemon[694]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux dnsmasq[28030]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Jan 17 14:28:05 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
Jan 17 14:28:07 nunux NetworkManager[27991]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
```

Please, tell me you know what's going. It has driven me crazy for too many months.

EDIT : I got a new laptop last week (with mint 17 too) and now I have the exact same problem on my new computer. Well, either I'm very unlucky, either mint (or ubuntu) has a serious network bug.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem on Debian before. I found a few ways to try to fix it. The first is to disable all Ethernet connections and make sure no start up script initiates any Ethernet connections. Then setup WiFi on start-up to automatically connect to your WiFi endpoint. 
You could try this in a start-up script: 

`service network-manager restart
ifconfig eth0 down 
ifconfig wlan0 up`

Another option is to fore the dchp to request an ip from the box. I found that ensured the connection. `udhcpc -i device_name` This may however cause some strange behaviors like static routes not holding true. I have noticed that sometimes my box will change ip addresses even though it is on a static route.

The problem could also be compatibility issue between the WiFi module in your box and your endpoint (router) or that the security on the endpoint disconnects specific connections automatically for some reason ie a specific request or behavior may trigger it.

Comment: Still no luck for now. I guess it's the compatibility issue you are talking about. I already tried differents security options but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
The best reply I can offer is to get an Ethernet cable and directly connect to the access point. However, this is only a workaround. It's possibly a bug in Ubuntu, after updating Ubuntu to the newest update of 14.04, the issue seems to be gone.

Comment: Well, I changed 3 things at the same time : 1/ new desktop, 2/ new OS (Mint 17 which is based on Ubuntu 14.04), and 3/ ethernet cable to wifi. The main issue is I cannot use ethernet anymore. I checked hardware/linux compatibility before purchassing anything, especially the network card . Yesterday, I had a 3 hours skype session (professional) and I had to restart network-manager like 10 times.

Comment: @Cyrille Please be specific. Why can't you use the cable?

Comment: I cannot use a cable since my box is not near my computer anymore.